# Getting javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: imap when trying to poll a mail server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

```
enter org.springframework.meption is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: imap
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:125)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:175
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:173)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:483)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:316)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.TimerManagerTaskScheduler$TimerScheduledFuture.timerExpired(TimerManagerTaskSched
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.TimerManagerTaskScheduler$ReschedulingTimerListener.timerExpired(TimerManagerTask
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.TimerImpl.callListenerMethod(TimerImpl.java:361)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.GenericTimer.run(GenericTimer.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:267)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:390)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:494)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:133)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:338)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:420)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1174)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.TimerImpl.runListenerAsCJWork(TimerImpl.java:490)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.fireAlarm(_Alarm.java:340)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:237)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: imap
    at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:798)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:578)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:540)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:239)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:259)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:285)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:111)
    ... 29 morecode here
```

I can ping the remote server ip so there are no connection issue.
I can run the same code in tomcat and is working fine.
The same code is giving me above error when i deploy it in web sphere.
Tried others things on Stack overflow none are working.
The jars are activation-1.1.jar, mail-1.4.5.jar .
Any pointers helpful .

Comment: plase provide a snippet of your code...

Comment: its connecting using spring integration http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html ....

Comment: If you can, update your [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) to version 1.5.3 or later. See: [skip unusable Store and Transport classes](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6668).  If that doesn't work provide the JavaMail debug output.

Comment: thats a great suggestion ..thanks will try now ...

Comment: MailSessions can be configured and provided by server. You should configure them on the server, remove activation.jar and mail.jar from your application and access mail session via JNDI.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for these answers and comments were certainly helpful .

Initially I used the below code :-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Which solved the imap provider issue. All is working in local but when I deployed the code on Websphere I was getting class cast exception

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain incompatible with javax.activation.DataContentHandler
```

Even though text_plain extends from DataContenHandler but kept on complaining about different class which tell it was getting loaded somewhere else . Then excluded activation jar as below to get it working

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: The com.sun.mail:javax.mail artifact includes all the providers for imap, smtp, and pop3 so you don't need separate jar files for them.  It also includes the full API definition so you don't need the javax.mail-api artifact.  The artifacts are described on the [JavaMail web page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Answer (score 2):

Well, in our tests we use this Gradle dependencies for the mail adapters:

```
mailVersion = '1.5.5'

testRuntime "com.sun.mail:javax.mail:$mailVersion"
testRuntime "com.sun.mail:smtp:$mailVersion"
testRuntime "com.sun.mail:pop3:$mailVersion"
testRuntime "com.sun.mail:imap:$mailVersion"
```

So, consider to add `com.sun.mail:imap:1.5.5` for your project.